# Real time velocity control with Moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, control, velocity

I am working on a research project involving robotic welding, and once I get the motion plan with moveit, I want the end effector to move in specific velocity along the weld path, based on camera feedback, i.e the velocity should be controlled in real time. Is there a built in feature to implement this in moveit or Moveit2?

I have also looked into [Extending the motion planning framework—MoveIt with advanced manipulation functions for industrial applications](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0736584523000352) but it is kinda difficult to implement and may not suit my application.

Answer (score 1):

Is [MoveIt Servo](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/examples/realtime_servo/realtime_servo_tutorial.html) suitable for you?

Answer (score 1):

- You could try writing a custom joint-space controller to use with MoveIt. In your controller, when you receive a trajectory command (i.e. "move here") you can do whatever you want at that point. Grab the trajectory endpoint and build your own path to it, send whatever velocity commands you think are best to your hardware etc. I built a [custom trajectory controller](https://github.com/01binary/str1ker/blob/master/src/trajectoryController.cpp) that works with MoveIt for my robot if you want an example. I can offer some minimal help if you run into trouble.
- You can try writing a custom motion planning plugin to use with MoveIt. The thing you are describing sounds like Cartesian path planning, except you don't want to use linear, cubic, or quintic interpolation - you want full control over the path waypoints from start to end. Writing a motion planning plugin will let you receive start and end points, then you can generate positions and velocities of the waypoints in the middle however you like. I also had to write a [custom motion planning plugin](https://github.com/01binary/str1ker/blob/master/src/plannerPlugin.cpp) if you want an example.